# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error on mac

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation

I am trying to work on a project for school from my personal mac laptop, the school computers I usually connect through using putty while I'm on their network. However, I am not on their network right now and need to work on this project. They provide the makefile and .h files so those are correct and everything was compiling on their machine, but when I pulled onto my mac and try running the makefile I get this error:

```
gcc -o test -g main.o linked_list_functions.o unit_tests.o

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_malloc_options", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Worked on a windows machine, but not on my machine so I am assuming I don't have something downloaded. I updated GCC, GDB, gperf through homebrew and I am still getting these errors.

Edit source code of file where it is called:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "unit_tests.h"

extern char *malloc_options ;           // Keep this line. Do not change it.

// Run the unit tests or as a "normal program".
// You can run this as a "normal program" if you want for a simple test of the $
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        malloc_options = "CFGSU" ;              // Keep this line. Do not chang$

        test() ;

        return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: This is what it can look like when you try to compile non-portable code on a different platform. `_malloc_options` is non-standard C API.

Comment: So am I just out of luck until I can use their system?

Comment: You haven't shown the source code where `_malloc_options` is called, but it would be recommended to re-work the code so these non-standard APIs aren't needed.

Comment: Posted the source code, we aren't suppose to have to change the code for this file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not implemented in OSX. (Sorry for the short and boring answer)

FreeBSD manpages includes *malloc_options* however in OSX it's not. So the linker correctly fails since it can't find the symbol you are trying to externally reference to.

The OSX synopsis ->

```
SYNOPSIS
     #include <stdlib.h>

     void *
     calloc(size_t count, size_t size);

     void
     free(void *ptr);

     void *
     malloc(size_t size);

     void *
     realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

     void *
     reallocf(void *ptr, size_t size);

     void *
     valloc(size_t size);
```

The FreeBSD Synopsis ->

```
SYNOPSIS
     #include <stdlib.h>

     void *
     malloc(size_t size);

     void *
     calloc(size_t number, size_t size);

     void *
     realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

     void *
     reallocf(void *ptr, size_t size);

     void
     free(void *ptr);

     char * malloc_options;
```

/A

Answer (score 0):

`malloc_options` is a non-portable extension. Are the systems in your lab running BSD? It appears to be only implemented on FreeBSD, and was removed in FreeBSD 10.

From the [FreeBSD 9.3 documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=malloc&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+9.3-RELEASE) `malloc_options` allows one to configure the way the `malloc()` allocator works in your process. Your code specifies `"CFGSU"` which enables the following options:

> - **`C`** - Double/halve the size of the maximum size class that is a multiple of the cacheline size (64).  Above this size, subpage spacing
>          (256 bytes) is used for size classes.  The default value is 512
>          bytes.
> - **`F`** - Halve/double the per-arena  minimum ratio of active to dirty
>          pages.  Some dirty unused pages may be allowed to accumulate,
>          within the limit set by the ratio, before informing the kernel
>          about at least half of those pages via madvise(2).  This provides
>          the kernel with sufficient information to recycle dirty pages if
>          physical memory becomes scarce and the pages remain unused.  The
>          default minimum ratio is 32:1; MALLOC_OPTIONS=6F will disable
>          dirty page purging.
> - **`G`** - Double/halve the approximate interval (counted in terms of
>          thread-specific cache allocation/deallocation events) between
>          full thread-specific cache garbage collection sweeps.  Garbage
>          collection is actually performed incrementally, one size class at
>          a time, in order to avoid large collection pauses.  The default
>          sweep interval is 8192; MALLOC_OPTIONS=14g will disable garbage
>          collection.
> - **`S`** - ??
> - **`U`** - Generate `utrace` entries for `ktrace(1)`,  for all operations. Consult the source  for details on this option.

As you can see, these are just tuning the allocator. For most programs, like your assignment, there's rarely a need to tune the memory allocator like this. Other `malloc_options` enable specific debug-related options which exist to detect invalid use of memory, which can be useful during development, but these are not in use by your code.

As a curious student, I would ask the instructor what the purpose of the `malloc_options` code is. You might go on to explain that you were trying to develop on a non-BSD system which doesn't support this nonstandard extension.

Furthermore, you can safely just disable that code while developing on your mac. I would use the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "unit_tests.h"

#ifdef __FreeBSD__
extern char *malloc_options ;
#endif /* __FreeBSD__ */

// Run the unit tests or as a "normal program".
// You can run this as a "normal program" if you want for a simple test of the $
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

#ifdef __FreeBSD__
        malloc_options = "CFGSU" ;
#endif /* __FreeBSD__ */

        test() ;

        return 0 ;
}
```